# When, how and why did עשרת הדברים turn into עשרת הדברות?

Tags: language, aseres-hadibros

God clearly spoke of עשרת הדברים in the Torah ([Exodus.34.28](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.34.28?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0), see also [Deut.4.13](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.4.13?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&qh=%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D)) or 10.4):

> וַיְהִי־שָׁם עִם־ה'אַרְבָּעִים יוֹם וְאַרְבָּעִים לַיְלָה... וַיִּכְתֹּב עַל־הַלֻּחֹת אֵת דִּבְרֵי הַבְּרִית **עֲשֶׂרֶת הַדְּבָרִים**׃

It continued some time in the rabbinic parlance, for example [Tamid.5.1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Tamid.5.1?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&qh=%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D):

> קָרְאוּ עֲשֶׂרֶת הַדְּבָרִים, שְׁמַע, וְהָיָה אִם שָׁמֹעַ...

But at some point, they turned into עשרת הדברות (for example [Shabbat.86b](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.86b.5?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&qh=%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA)):

> תָּנוּ רַבָּנַן: בְּשִׁשִּׁי בַּחֹדֶשׁ נִיתְּנוּ עֲשֶׂרֶת הַדִּבְּרוֹת לְיִשְׂרָאֵל.

It appears that they stayed that way ever since.

When, how and why did עשרת הדברים turn into עשרת הדברות? Is there an argument about the use of the masculine or the feminine between different schools? Why would such a foundational term be altered?